# Game Requests appearing in Facebook Notifications area - How do I stop it?

Tags: facebook, notifications

In the last day or so, I have started getting game notifications (Mafia Wars) in the notifications bar at the top of the FaceBook screen (under the globe). Others seem to be complaining about this too on FaceBook.

Is there a way to make it go back to not showing these in the notification drop-down like it used to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding it is a feature the FaceBook is currently testing. Seems the only way currently to stop those notifications is to uninstall those applications.